# Who is in charge of determining a pronunciation?

Tags: american-english

Recently I hear many words that sound different than they used to. There are the classic changes in words like *pecan* and *Uranus*. But the word that bugs me most now is *caramel*. Is there some group in America that has control of pronunciation?

Personally, once I learn a word, I will never change how I say it. Love them pee cans.

Comment: What's the "new" pronunciation? I know of two, but I wasn't aware either was older...

Comment: "Who is in charge" - for English, everybody and nobody.

Comment: "Who is in charge" — for every living language, everybody and nobody. FTFY @J. M. (^_^)

Comment: Language (pronunciation included) evolves too. The most favourite pronunciations survive. Natural selection of word pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Those of us from the Western United States would believe that we speak the "purest" form of American English (if such a thing exists)--I think this is what's being called "TV English" in the other post, although as a speaker of this dialect, my lip curls at such a designation.

However, even among us, we differ on pronunciations/word choice. A few examples: 1) the pop v. soda debate, which many argue has regional roots, although I've never been able to map it specifically; 2) bag being pronounced as either "baag" or "beg"; 3) tour being pronounced as either "too-er" or "tore".

As an aside, the irony I find is that I imagine the majority of Americans do NOT speak in our "generic" dialect, considering the density of population in other parts of the US (besides perhaps California).

However, I think this is one of the hallmarks of English. It does not have a regulating body like the French language. No one and everyone (thank you, J.M.) regulates English.

Comment: [Pop vs Soda (vs Coke/other) map](http://popvssoda.com/).

Comment: The French language is not anywhere as heavily regulated as some would have you believe, *especially* when it comes to pronunciation. Two of my neighbors are native speakers of French, but they sometimes have trouble understanding each other, and *neither* of them pronounces things the way I was taught to back in my school days. Neither of them can even get a simple *bonsoir* "right"!

Answer (score 0):

What influence do you think TV has on pronunciation? Here, in Australia, there is basically one accent but in America there seems a wide variety. Most American TV shows seem to be in TV-English, a generic accent. However, some shows use regional accents. Do you think that when an accent gets a wider audience via TV that the eccentricities of that accent spread?

BTW: I have to watch 'The Wire' on DVD so I can turn on subtitles. A Baltimore accent is just gibberish to me.

Comment: To be fair, a guy in Baltimore would probably require subtitles to watch an Australian TV show. ;)